# Reading motor limit switches with Arduino

Tags: arduino, motor, motor-controller

I'm building a window blinds system. I have an arduino powering a motor via a DRV8833 Dual-H bridge controller. At the limits of each direction of motion, I have limit switches that kill the power to the motor in that direction. I also want the arduino to read when the limits are hit, but I can't feed the raw power from the limit switch into an input pin as it will exceed the 3.3V logic inputs.

I've got what I'm calling forward working with an NPN transistor to feed 3.3V logic when its corresponding limit switch is hit. **However I'm really struggling figuring out the wiring to determine when the reverse limit switch is hit**. In that case you end up with a negative voltage in a sense coming from the limit switch. I've had a couple of random configurations that seemed to work, but not consistently. I'm attaching diagram of what I have in place currently. In this diagram, I'm representing the reverse and forward directions separately with reversed voltage sources even though in practice, the two limit switches are next to each other between the DRV8833 and the motor (represented by lamp). I have diodes across the limits to allow motion in the opposite direction when a limit is hit. I have Q8 being activated when SW7 is hit and the arduino pin reads the switch activation. **I need help getting SW5 to indicate to the arduino when it's been hit**. Note resistors are just default ratings in diagram.

[image]
[Circuit Lab](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/rsq3myr8fq2g/second-limit-switch/)

Comment: With the current circuit, pin3 is *always* connected to 3.3V. If Q6 turns ON, what limits the current through Q6 ?

Comment: Why not use the **same** scheme as SW7 ? input to Q8 is low when motor is running and input to Q8 is high (8V) when motor is not running. If you use the same scheme for SW5 also, only difference is that you will get high when motor is running and low when motor is not running. Just do a logical inversion **inside** the arduino code.

Comment: Are the BJTs necessary?  Can this not be done with voltages dividers?

Comment: I'm a total newb at circuitry so there is possibly a better way to do this than BJT. I hadn't thought about voltage dividing but I just felt like there were too many variables to ensure I get a clear an accurate and safe voltage into the input pin. I don't know at this point what voltage I'll need to run the motor at (it's on a buck converter so I can set voltage) and PWM may also come into play and I don't under stand how PWM affects things. It's possible I don't have a grasp of how VD works and it may be viable. I just don't have the knowledge or experience under my belt.

Comment: @AJN: The circuit above I know is not correct. It was me just throwing random things into circuitlab to see if something stuck. As for using same scheme, my first attempt was to do just that. A verbatim copy of what I'm using for forward. I have that version here: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/79cbpvrdg5e3/blinds-motor-drive/. In that case, PIN3 gets tripped almost immediately after the motor reverses, regardless of limit switch state. I just tested that again and that's the behavior I see regardless of what logic I set for the pin.

Comment: This would perhaps be simpler if you used only a positive power supply and used your H-Bridge IC to swap the polarity to the motor only.  However, to monitor a negative voltage you can with care build a voltage divider referenced to the MCU positive supply instead of ground.  A clamping diode may also play a role.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not really clear on what you mean but I'd like to understand if I'm missing it. The only polarity shift that is occurring is between the H-Bridge and the motor, which has the two limit switches in line? I'm not changing the power supply anywhere else in the system.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You're the 2nd person to mention a voltage divider so I'll try to find an example of what you're referring to online. My issue is that my circuit seems to be acting badly when it comes to voltages and currents, perhaps related to another part of the build that includes a voltage booster to 24v to power a clutch. I get erratic motor speeds seemingly at the whims of how the circuit is feeling that day. I haven't had time to track down what the variables are. Perhaps unintended or missing capacitance somewhere. That's why I was aiming to use the reference 3.3V to run to logic.

Comment: Voltage converters feeding motors are generally a very bad idea

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you elaborate a bit on that? That seems like a very limiting restriction. The suggestion is that motor voltage should match up with power input voltage? I'll do a search on that. I'll be powering this project with two 18650 Lion so around 8v or so of power... and was shooting for around 5-6v to the little motor I'm using. I've got one booster to get me 24V for the electric clutch and one buck to get me around 5v for the motor. Although... with the voltage drop I end up getting in the circuit, I probably could straight wire the motors and still end up at a safe voltage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using limit switches with DPDT contacts would be one more way to meet your requirement of having hardwired limit switches with status feed back to the controller.

Another alternative would be to wire the limit switches to the controller inputs and have only software control.

Comment: While these are options, it is false to claim that they are the only ways to solve the problem.  The stated plan of monitoring a negative voltage is achievable.

Comment: So @vu2nan, are you recommending that instead of the SPDT limit switches I have now, I could use a DPDT switch to essentially create a separate circuit that gets activated when the switch is thrown? That circuit could be at 3.3V reference and I don't have to deal with whatever voltage the motor is running? That actually sounds like a good idea that hadn't occurred to me. I didn't know DPDT limits existed. Looks like they are much harder to buy and more expensive but they would simplify things if I'm understanding correctly. Then I wouldn't need the BJTs. XV-156-2C25 looks like a good option

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you very much for pointing it out. It was not my intention to make such a claim. My answer has been amended.

Comment: I just ordered some DPDT limits from Amazon for Thursday delivery. From circuit lab... it seems like your idea would work great and simplifies things even if it raises the cost a bit. https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/ewkka5paqveh/blinds-with-dpdt-limits If it works once I get the parts, I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: If I was going to take one of the ideas from this answer and run with it, it would be the idea of making the control always go via the MCU software

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm afraid I don't understand what you guys mean when you say that. Are you saying to not have the limit switches wired inline with the motors... just have them wired to the MCU and have it stop the motors via software? If that's the case I guess I could do that. My concern was if my software had a bug or didn't work properly, it would over spin the blinds past their breaking point and break them.

Comment: Hi Wesley, I'm sorry I could not reply earlier as there was a call for dinner! I wanted to convey that your understanding is right and XV-156-2C25 is okay. You have  wasted no time in ordering! I agree with you that hardwiring the limit switches is the ultimate failsafe method. I had suggested control via software in order to salvage the SPDT switches. In that case, with NC contacts wired to the controller inputs, the motor would stop in the event of a limit switch wire break too. You could incorporate this feature (NC contacts to controller inputs), in the new schematic, as a safety back-up.